# Can user change directives in Single Page Application Authorizaiton

Tags: angular, reactjs, authorization, vuejs2, single-page-application

I am new at SPA
like Angular ,React , Vue.js by the way im using Vue.js. We are sending all js files to user but what about client side directive protection.

For example. I am rendering delete button for admin but i am not rendering for user. Is this any way to user can `v-if="false" to true` to render that button. (Button or another rendered part by authorization)

Of course we need to put server side validation for it but i need to know what can user do with this js. Are there any layer with browser and with js which protected by browser

Comment: can use change it ? `yes`. Normal users won't do any kind of hacking, and most of the novice developers will not do that. And to protect, as you said, `server side validation`. Anything on the browser is exposed and is vulnerable .

Comment: So again only way to protect our server token with https right? Seperating SPA pages by authorization is not a true thing always it can be manipulated